# Accessing HBase from BIRT using Phoenix

Tags: hbase, birt, apache-phoenix

My primary requirement is to use data in HBase for reporting. BIRT is my reporting tool. Phoenix is a JDBC client that allows querying HBase data with SQL like queries. Now, Is there a way for me to use BIRT to report from HBase through Phoenix? Any pointers is much appreciated.

**Edit:**
Thanks Simulant for your response. This is what I have tried.

1. Created a Java class file that access data from my HBASE cluster through Phoenix. Referred example from link: http://www.javaworld.com/article/3030214/big-data/open-source-java-projects-apache-phoenix.html.
2. Instead of showing the fetched data in Console I created a method myPhoenixDatabase() that converts the data to JSON String and
   returns.
3. In BIRT report, I used scripted datasource. In the script for dataset, I imported the package that has the class mentioned in (1) and (2), parsed the JSON array that is being returned from myPhoenixDatabase() and mapped
   them to my dataset fields.

**BIRT Dataset Script:**

**Open Method**

```
importPackage(Packages.com.geekcap.javaworld.phoenixexample);
pe = new Packages.com.geekcap.javaworld.phoenixexample.PhoenixExample();
var jsontext = pe.myPhoenixDatabase();
myJSONObject = eval ("(" + jsontext + ")");
len = myJSONObject.length; 
count=0;
```

**Fetch Method**

```
if(count < len)
{
    var EmpID     = myJSONObject[count].EMPID;
    var Name   = myJSONObject[count].NAME;
    var Designation    = myJSONObject[count].DESIGNATION;
    row["EmpID"] = EmpID;
    row["Name"]= Name;
    row["Designation"]= Designation;
    count++;
    return true;
}
return false;
```

**Issues:**

1. This works fine only on the first execution after opening ECLIPSE. In subsequent runs the return value from the function was NULL and it throws error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null".
2. A weird workaround fixed this issue, calling the function twice, once from Open method of dataset script and second time from Afteropen method, fixed this issue.
3. But still I am not able to get the report working from Tomcat server.

I have uploaded the class, Maven POM and report files. Sorry for a long description. Any help would be much appreciated. 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5pKuCLloQdHM09HN1E4MndQQ1k&usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried creating a SQL-Datasource and use phoenix as JDBC-Driver? Please show what you have tried so far and ask for a concrete problem you are facing.

Comment: @Simulant : I tried creating a Datasource with type as "Generic JDBC Driver" and added the Phoenix-Core-HBase-Version.jar file. But creating a dataset using the same datasource did not take me to the Query editor window nor it threw any error. I am not sure if Phoenix JDBC driver is compatible with BIRT. I had to use scripted datasource. Please see my edit. Thanks.